# MiKTeX, LaTeX: Error with \newwrite output file and writing with \write -- Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, io, latex, pdflatex, miktex

Using TeXworks v0.6.5 (MiKTeX 20.7) on Windows 10 Home, I am trying to write a line to a text file.

When typesetting this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\justafile

\begin{document}

% Write to text file:

\immediate\openout\justafile=exam.txt

\immediate\write\justafile{Chosen questions: bla, bla and bla.}

\immediate\closeout\justafile

\end{document}
```

the console outputs the following message (last 5 lines of the compilation log):

```
No pages of output.
Transcript written on example.log.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log
```

The log file carries the following error messages:

```
2020-09-06 19:47:38,817-0400 INFO  texify - this process (4764) started by 'miktex-texworks' with   command line: "C:\Users\Miriam Briskman\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" --pdf --synctex=1 --clean example.tex
2020-09-06 19:47:38,880-0400 INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex --synctex=1 "C:/Users/Miriam Briskman/OneDrive/Desktop/Brooklyn College/Fall 2020/CISC 1050/Tests/Test Pool/New folder\example.tex"
2020-09-06 19:47:39,249-0400 INFO  texify.core - start process: pdflatex --synctex=1 "C:/Users/Miriam Briskman/OneDrive/Desktop/Brooklyn College/Fall 2020/CISC 1050/Tests/Test Pool/New folder\example.tex"
2020-09-06 19:47:39,587-0400 ERROR texify.core - The system cannot find the file specified.

2020-09-06 19:47:39,587-0400 ERROR texify.core - Function: CopyFileW
2020-09-06 19:47:39,587-0400 ERROR texify.core - Result: 2
2020-09-06 19:47:39,587-0400 ERROR texify.core - Data: existing="C:/Users/MIRIAM~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mik68959/_src\example.pdf", path="C:/Users/Miriam Briskman/OneDrive/Desktop/Brooklyn College/Fall 2020/CISC 1050/Tests/Test Pool/New folder\example.pdf"
2020-09-06 19:47:39,587-0400 ERROR texify.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:383
2020-09-06 19:47:39,592-0400 FATAL texify - Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

2020-09-06 19:47:39,592-0400 FATAL texify - Info: existing="C:/Users/MIRIAM~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mik68959/_src\example.pdf", path="C:/Users/Miriam Briskman/OneDrive/Desktop/Brooklyn College/Fall 2020/CISC 1050/Tests/Test Pool/New folder\example.pdf"
2020-09-06 19:47:39,592-0400 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2020-09-06 19:47:39,592-0400 FATAL texify - Line: 383
```

Below is a link to a screenshot of the TeXworks console with the code:

[TeXworks console with the problematic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK004.jpg)

I installed all the recent updates using the MiKTeX console, but this did not solve the issue.

What is the source of the error, and how should I fix it?

Comment: Can you directly compile with pdflatex instead of texify? Texify is notorious for throwing away all useful error messages....

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, great thanks! When I change the processing tool from pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX to just pdfLaTeX, the code compiles normally, and the output file is successfully created and modified. Would you like to add this suggestion as an answer to the question in case you have a specific suspicion of what goes wrong with texify? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I have no idea what goes wrong with texify and that is exactly the problem why I advice to stay away from it. When using latex directly, it will always tell what the problem is. This might not always understandable to every user but at least one can take the information to get help online.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for the solution and for the advice, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay way from `texify` whenever possible.

- you never know what exactly texify is doing
- texify is notorious for throwing away all helpful output that would allow users to actually debug their problems

Instead I suggest to either

- directly compile with `pdflatex` if you have a simple document without extra stuff like bibliographies etc.
- for more complex documents, compile with an automatisation tool like `latexmk`. This will automatically determine the required number of tex runs, will invoke bibtex/biber or any other tools your document might need